# creating digital time in canvas tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

I am newbie in Python using tkinter and I have a problem that I cant solve.[Digital time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oKof.png)
I want to put digital time in the the upper right corner of my application (Please see the picture). I tried to search on net on how to create a digital time but it is on global root and frame configuration and I cant find a digital clock made for canvas. I also want to put my buttons in middle using grid, but I have no luck finding a solution. Can any one please help me? Ill paste my code here.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import date
import time
import sys


class main_menu(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('System')
        self.root.geometry('780x488')

        self.background = PhotoImage(file='images/bg.png')
        self.canvas = Canvas (root)
        self.canvas.grid(sticky=N+S+W+E)
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0, image=self.background, anchor="nw")

        self.scan_photo = PhotoImage (file='images/scan.png')
        self.logs_photo = PhotoImage (file='images/logs.png')
        self.settings_photo = PhotoImage (file='images/settings.png')

        self.scan_btn = Button (self.canvas, image=self.scan_photo, borderwidth=0, command=self.StartScan)
        self.scan_win = self.canvas.create_window(225, 100, anchor="nw", window=self.scan_btn)
        self.logs_btn = Button (self.canvas, image=self.logs_photo, borderwidth=0, command=self.Logs)
        self.logs_win = self.canvas.create_window(225, 200, anchor="nw", window=self.logs_btn)
        self.settings_btn = Button (self.canvas, image=self.settings_photo, borderwidth=0, command=self.Settings)
        self.settings_win = self.canvas.create_window(225, 300, anchor="nw", window=self.settings_btn)

        self.today = date.today()
        self.format = self.today.strftime("%b. %d, %Y")
        self.canvas.create_text(730, 30, text=self.format, font=("Helvetica", 10))

        self.InstructionsLabel = Label(root, text="""
            

            tadahhhhhh""", fg="black", font=("Calibri", 14))

        self.Return_photo = PhotoImage (file='images/back_24x24.png')
        self.ReturnMenu_btn = Button (self.canvas, image=self.Return_photo, background='white',activebackground='white', borderwidth=0, command=self.MainMenu)
        self.ReturnMenu_win = self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor="nw", window=self.ReturnMenu_btn)
        ###self.ReturnMenu = Button(root, image=self.back_photo, command=self.MainMenu, )
        self.MainMenu()

    def MainMenu(self):
        self.RemoveAll()
        self.ReturnMenu_btn.grid_remove()
        self.scan_btn.grid(padx=215)
        self.logs_btn.grid(padx=215)
        self.settings_btn.grid(padx=215)

    def StartScan(self):
        self.RemoveAll()

    def Logs(self):
        self.RemoveAll()
        self.ReturnMenu.grid()

    def Settings(self):
        self.RemoveAll()
        self.ReturnMenu.grid()

    def RemoveAll(self):
        self.scan_btn.grid_remove()
        self.logs_btn.grid_remove()
        self.settings_btn.grid_remove()
        self.InstructionsLabel.grid_remove()
        self.ReturnMenu_btn.grid_remove()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    main_menu = main_menu(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: a suggestion: don't use `*` when importing since it is not the best practice to do so, instead either just import `import module_name` or import what You need. also do this `ClassName()` instead of `ClassName ()`

Comment: So you want "Digital time" (word) or simply the time to be at the upper right corner?

Comment: hello I want to display the time in the upper right corner.

Comment: @Xian please tag using @ when you are replying to someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To place the time in the upper right corner you need to know the width of the canvas. So use `canvas.winfo_width()` to get the width of the canvas and subtract some number to place it at the desired position.

If you want the time to stay at the top-right even if the window is resized then bind Configure to a function and move the text using `.coords` or `.moveto`.

Sample code(this code will make sure that the time is always at the upper right corner).

```py
from tkinter import font
class MainMenu:
    def __init__(self, root):        
        ...
        self.time = self.canvas.create_text(0, 0, text=self.format, font=("Helvetica", 10))
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.adjustTimePosition)
        ...
    def adjustTimePosition(self, event):

        family, size = self.canvas.itemcget(self.time, 'font').split()  # get the font-family and font size
        text = self.canvas.itemcget(self.time, 'text')
        
        txt_font = font.Font(family=family, size=size)
        width, height = txt_font.measure(text), txt_font.metrics("ascent")  # measures the width and height of the text
        self.canvas.coords(self.time, self.canvas.winfo_width()-width, height)  # moves the text
```